# jQuery: animate element to strecth evenly to left and right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

Current effect:

[image: Current effect]

Desired effect:

[image: Desired effect]

I think the pics are pretty self-explanatory..

- On mouse hover, the current

  item where the cursor is hovering should increase in width, 1 item above and below will have the same effect with less change. However, the

  item only scale to the right side and not equally to both sides from its center.

You might wanna take a look at the code so I hosted the files in a public folder in DropBox:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33331786/InflatingMenu/index.html

Comment: since you'll be modifying the style you could add position: relative; to all the .item and then when one is hovered over set it's left value to negative half the extra distance; so the main one being hovered goes -1em to the left then expands 2em to the right through animation

Comment: I removed all the CSS from `#nav`, `nav` and `.container` and that seemed to work http://jsfiddle.net/2qLaN/

Comment: @borislemke I am guessing it's because of the `width` change, `text-align:center;` needs to readjust. `jQuery` changes the `width` really fast in more steps. Try playing a little around with `easing` and `animation speed`